# How to connect GCP bucket using JDBC Driver

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-platform, bucket

We need to read the flat file or CSV file tabular data from GCP bucket using JDBC.
We couldn't find any JDBC driver by using it we can establish the connection with the GCP Bucket.

Could you please suggest us any solution on how to connect to GCP bucket using JDBC.

Comment: This sounds like a very specific use-case including two orthogonal concerns. I don't think that such a JDBC driver exists. In any case, asking for external resources and suggestions for libraries is off-topic.

Comment: "A JDBC driver is a software component enabling a Java application to interact with a database." and there's no way to use something like this to connect to GCP Storage bucket. Have a look at [Java Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) and some code samples  [Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples). Please update your question with extra details about your use case.